# Calculate $|\text{Dom}f|-|\text{Im}f|$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If we have the function

$$f(n) = \begin{cases}
n/2, & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
5n+7, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

how can I calculate $|\text{Dom}f|-|\text{Im}f|$?

It is clear that $\text{Dom}f=\mathbb N$ and $\text{Im}f\subset \mathbb N$ is infinite. Does that mean that the answer is $0$? Or $\infty$ because there are infinite elements that are not in $\text{Im}f$?

Comment: Or.... undefined?

Comment: Where did you see this question, because it does not make sense to subtract infinity from infinity..

Comment: @Shashi I know it is indeterminate, but isn't there a way to expand it to get a valid determinated answer?

Comment: I don't know. Have a nice day!

Comment: Maybe you're asked to find $|Dom(f) \setminus Im(f)|$?

Comment: @cronos2 Nope. But the property that $|Dom(f)|-|Im(f)|\leq |Dom(f)-Im(f)|$ i think it is useful.

Comment: @Garmekain that only works for numbers, not sets. And even if they weren't sets, infinite cardinals don't apply either.

Comment: You can't say that $|Dom(f)|-|Im(f)|\leq |Dom(f)-Im(f)|$ hold since $|Dom(f)|-|Im(f)|$ is not well defined if we talk about infinite sets. On the other hand when defining a function, one *should* also say what the domain and co-domain is, thus maybe $f$ is only defined on numbers in $\{1,\ldots, 10\}$ or possibly calculating it depending on n i.e.  $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ is doable.